# Android: Hiding/revealing bottom navigation view causes lost of scroll state

Tags: android, scroll

I have an MainActivity with FrameLayout and BottomNavigation.

It looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/layoutActivityMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        tools:context=".view.main.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/splash"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:elevation="100dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgBgSplash"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/bg_start" />

        <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/box"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@id/bottomBox"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgIconStart"
                    android:layout_width="98dp"
                    android:layout_height="98dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:alpha="0.9"
                    android:paddingBottom="18dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_icon_start"
                    android:tint="@android:color/white" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/bottomBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <com.example.custom.views.CustomProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progress"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                    android:indeterminateTint="@android:color/white"
                    android:progressTint="@android:color/white" />

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnRetry"
                    style="@style/buttonStyleWhite"
                    android:layout_width="256dp"
                    android:layout_height="54dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                    android:text="@string/x_001_start_splash_btn_retry"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/navigationBottom" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigationBottom"
            style="Widget.BottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_navigation_with_border"
            app:itemIconSize="30dp"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My problem which causes me headache:
if I hide and then reveal the BottomNavigationView via GONE and then VISIBLE ... the Fragment inside the Framelayout loses it's scroll state. Also all image views (with glide) are redrawn again which causes some visible side effects (kind of tilt).

Do you have any ideas what can I do to not lose the scroll state and get rid of the side effects described above?

This is how I hide and reveal the BottomNavigationView in the MainActivity:

```
fun hideBottomNavBar() {
        if (navigationBottom.isVisible) {
            navigationBottom.animate()
                .yBy(navigationBottom.height.toFloat())
                .withEndAction { navigationBottom.visibility = View.GONE }
                .start()
        }
    }

    fun revealBottomNavBar() {
        if (!navigationBottom.isVisible) {
            navigationBottom.animate()
                .yBy(-navigationBottom.height.toFloat())
                .withStartAction { navigationBottom.visibility = View.VISIBLE }
                .start()
        }
    }
```

Comment: I also tried set it to INVISIBLE, but it affects the screens without BottomNavBar cause it still occupies the space of the bar.

Comment: Also moving to Constraint Layout does no effect cause the content in Framelayout still be redrawn after BottomNavBar is set to gone.

Comment: if you're animating the BottomBar in and out of the screen, doesn't seem necessary to set it to `GONE/VISIBLE` anyway. Does the same effect happen if you skip the Visibility changes at the start and end of the animation?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the parent `RelativeLayout` with **FrameLayout** and then I guess you wouldn''t be facing this issue because framelayout will arrange the views in a stack view with the last one being at top. Give margin bottom to your inner FrameLayout where you'll be attaching the fragment equal to the bottomNavigation height. Try this out

```
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            andorid:margin_bottom   />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigationBottom"
            style="Widget.BottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_navigation_with_border"
            app:itemIconSize="30dp"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Hope this should work.

Comment: Sadly it would not work because I haven't postet the whole layout file. My bad :( But I've updated the question now!